# How to change the encoding of the text in the current buffer?

Tags: encoding

I have written a file with `:set fileencoding=ISO-2022-JP` `:wq`.
When I try to open it again it is completely unreadable. `:set encoding?` shows that vim has misinterpreted the content as encoding=utf-8.
When I try to change the encoding with `:set encoding=ISO-2022-JP` vim show as a red text for a shorter time than I could read it, but `:messages` shows the error message `E474: Invalid argument: encoding=ISO-2022-JP`.

I have also tried `:e ++encoding=ISO-2022-JP` but without success, no error message, the text stays the same gibberish.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the option `encoding` is the coding used in Vim internally. This should be of no consequence to your problem. What does `:set fileencoding?` show after loading the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vivian's answer covers the one-shot case. If you regularly handle files saved in an esoteric (read: non-western) encoding, it will help to tweak the `fileencodings` (note the trailing 's') option to your needs.

In your `vimrc` you could do something like:

```
set fileencodings=iso-2022-jp,ucs-bom,utf-8,default
```

Order is important here as Vim will pick the first encoding that works without errors. The actual encodings to try depend on the files you expect to encounter. Spend some thought on getting this option right and *do not copy this line verbatim.*

If set up correctly, it will make Vim guess the right `fileencoding` when opening a file.

See [`:help 'fileencoding'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27fileencoding%27) and [`:help 'fileencodings'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27fileencodings%27) for more information.

Comment: interesting, with `:set fileencodings=iso-2022-jp` `:e`  it loads the file correctly, with `:set fileencodings=utf-8,iso-2022-jp` `:e` it loads it as utf-8

Comment: As I wrote (and as `:help fileencodings` says as well) the *order* is important. Vim will try the entries in the list from the start and pick the first one that works. So if whatever you load could be valid utf-8, it will pick it.

Comment: yes, makes sense. I had realized that the order is important, I wanted it to try utf-8 first because utf-8 is more common. What I failed to realize was that those weird unprintable characters vim was showing are actually valid utf-8 characters so there is no way for vim to know that this was not the correct encoding.

Comment: You may run into problems either way. Guessing encodings is error prone. If you want to use a specific encoding for a file, use `++enc` as per Vivian's answer.

Comment: `++enc` does not work for me, so I'll just temporarily set `fileencodings` to the one encoding that I want to use

Answer (score 1):

To help Vim open the file (e.g. foo.txt) with the correct encoding (e.g. cp932) you can do:

```
:e ++enc=cp932 foo.txt
```

I suppose you have to convert your file first into a supported Japanese encoding (e.g. `cp932`, `euc-jp`, `sjis`)

More information about the supported encoding with `:help mbyte-encoding`.

I'm not sure `ISO-2022-JP` is supported.

It seems that `ISO-2022-JP` is somehow related to `sjis` the following is probably worth trying:

```
:e ++enc=sjis foo.txt
```

The documentation recommends [nkf](https://github.com/nurse/nkf) to convert the Kanji file. With the tool installed you can do:

```
:e ++enc=euc-jp foo.txt
:%!nkf -e
```

Remark: If the file is open with the wrong encoding to my knowledge you have to reopen it using the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure about the "ISO-2022-JP not supported", e.g. `:help 'fileencodings'` features an example on `iso-2022-jp`. Maybe the caps are the problem?

Comment: @Friedrich no, `:set encoding=iso-2022-jp` gives the same error message

Comment: @jakun `encoding` is the wrong option as I wrote in my comment on your question. Do *not* `:set encoding`.

Comment: @Friedrich thank you, I had not yet seen your comment on my question. `:set fileencoding?` shows fileencoding=utf-8.

Comment: I see `iso-2022-jp` is not in the list of supported values for `encoding` (which is why it doesn't work). For `fileencoding` these and more (depending on OS and installed libs) are supported so there's a chance for `iso-2022-jp` to work as `fileencoding` only. A definitive list would be nice but I see how it would be hard to write one.